# Mathematical Comparison Between Marginal and Conditional Variances

Tags: probability, random-variables, variance

**Question:** What I want to do is to mathematically prove the following two inequalities:
$$Var(Y) \geq Var(Y | X)$$
$$Var(Y | X_1) \geq Var(Y | X_1, X_2)$$

Some hint to the proof will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**Details**
Let $X_1, X_2$, and $Y$ be continuous random variables. We can also assume that they are not independent from each other.

Comment: Just checking -- did the answer below actually answer your question? (if so, consider [accepting it](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/); if not, please let me know how, so that I can improve it).

Comment: Yes, yes definetely!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is **not** true. *(More precisely, this equality does not really make sense, at least not the way you most likely intended.)*

By definition,
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(Y\mid X) &= \mathbb{E}[(Y - \mathbb{E}[Y\mid X])^{2}\mid X]
= \mathbb{E}[Y^2 - 2Y\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X]+\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X]^{2}\mid X]\\
&= \mathbb{E}[Y^2\mid X] - 2\mathbb{E}[Y\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X]\mid X]+\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X]^{2}\mid X]\\
&= \mathbb{E}[Y^2\mid X] - 2\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X]^2+\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X]^{2}\\
&= \mathbb{E}[Y^2\mid X] - \mathbb{E}[Y\mid X]^2
\end{align}$$
expanding and using the fact that $\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X]$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable.

Note that this is not a constant, but a *random variable*, so intuitively the inequality you seek is a "type error."

To see a concrete example, consider the simplest case, when $Y$ has an arbitrary distribution (to be picked later) and $X=Y^2$:, say for simplicity $Y=RN$ where is a Rademacher random variable (uniform on $\{-1,1\}$) independent of $N$ which is Gaussian$(0,1)$.

Then $\mathbb{E}[Y^2\mid X] = \mathbb{E}[X\mid X] = X$, $\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X]^2 = \mathbb{E}[Y\mid Y^2]^2 = \mathbb{E}[RN\mid N^2]^2= \mathbb{E}[R]\mathbb{E}[N\mid N^2]^2=0$ so that $\operatorname{Var}(Y\mid X) = X$.

But
$\operatorname{Var}(Y)$ is just a nice number, and since $X$ is continuous and supported on $\mathbb{R}$ we have $\mathbb{P}\{X > \operatorname{Var}(Y) \} > 0$.

That is,

> $$\mathbb{P}\{\operatorname{Var}(Y\mid X) > \operatorname{Var}(Y) \} > 0$$

---

By the [law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance), however, you *do* have:
$$
\operatorname{Var} Y 
= \mathbb{E}[\operatorname{Var}( Y \mid X)] + \underbrace{\operatorname{Var}( \mathbb{E}[Y\mid X])}_{\geq 0}
\geq \mathbb{E}[\operatorname{Var}( Y \mid X)].
$$
Note that here both LHS and RHS are "numbers."

Comment: You're welcome — glad it helped.